# Illegal reference to array

Tags: arrays, sas

The first code seems to work, but the second is saying there is an illegal reference to array in the log. I am trying to assign new values to specific quarters, which are separate variables, without overriding the previous quarter values. So, the second example will change values for specific `ID`, but only for `QR3` to `QR10`.

```
data comb_new;
    set comb_new;
        array DQR(10) QR1-QR10;
            do i = 1 to 10;
                if id = "071800" then DQR(i) = 6;
                end;
            drop i;
run;
```

Second:

```
data comb_new;
    set comb_new;
        array p3t (8) QR3-QR10;
            do i = 1 to 8;
            if id = "141956" then p3t(i) = 6;
            end;
                if id = "461818" then p3t(i) = 6;
                end;
                if id = "261808" then p3t(i) = 6;
                end;
                if id = "261893" then p3t(i) = 6;
                end;
                if id = "261894" then p3t(i) = 6;
                end;
                if id = "011936" then p3t(i) = 6;
                end;
                if id = "141854" then p3t(i) = 6;
                end;
                if id = "061883" then p3t(i) = 6;
                end;
            drop i;
run;
```

Comment: That code should have a lot of errors, but not that one.  You have too many ENDs there, remove them all except the last one.  `end` is terminating the `do` loop, it has nothing to do with the if statements.

Comment: The reason you get that error is the do loop terminates at the first end.  At the end of the loop `i` equals 9, which is outside the array.  You then try to assign values to `p3t[9]`, which is bad.  @Joe is correct.  Fix the `end;` issue.

Comment: Illegal reference means the array wasn't used properly (leaving out the bracket selection most commonly).  You would get an Array Subscript Out of Bounds error if that's the case.  `data _null_; array x[5]; x[6]=3; run;` for example.  This error is more like `data _null_; array x[5]; x=3; run;`.

Answer (score 1):

First change your array name from `p3t` to something without a number, like `pat`. SAS is more finicky about array names, and you may eliminate the error just by doing that.

Second, check your dataset `comb_new` after the conclusion of the first `DATA` step. An illegal reference will happen if any of the variables `QR3-QR10` don't exist in your dataset.